# Eloqua to Salesforce Integration Issue

Tags: integration, case, fields

I have integrated Eloqua to Salesforce to upload Cases. It is working as expected however the only problem is that the Status of the case always goes to New(which is the default value of Status in Salesforce),  irrespective of what is the Status value in Eloqua.

Please suggest if there is any way so that I can retain the status that is present in Eloqua.

Comment: 1) are there workflows/process builder/triggers in target org that set status to New on Case insert?  or .... 2) Are you mapping the status field from Eloqua?

Comment: @crop1645 : I am mapping the status field from Eloqua, there is no workflow rule, trigger or process builder involved.

Comment: 1) did you look at debug log under whatever user eloqua uses to sync to SFDC to be sure there is nothing that happens to the Case after the case is created. For example, does eloqua sync(create) the Case without status, hence defaults to new, then eloqua syncs back from salesforce status=new that smashes the eloqua value of status and then eloqua resyncs back to sfdc?  I've seen these circular syncs before (2) any chance you have a custom `status__c` field that you are confusing with the OOB `status` field?